# Operation table of Hasse diagram

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

Consider the following Hasse diagram:

[image]

My book gives the following join and meet operation tables for this diagram:

$$\begin{array}{|c || c | c|}
\hline
Subset & x \wedge y & x \vee y \\
\hline
\{a,b\} & 0 & 1 \\
\{a,c\} & c & a \\
\{a,1\} & a & 1 \\
\{a,0\} & 0 & a \\
\{b,c\} & 0 & 1 \\
\{b,a\} & 0 & 1 \\
\{b,1\} & b & 1 \\
\{b,0\} & 0 & b \\
\{c,a\} & c & a \\
\{c,1\} & c & 1 \\
\{c,b\} & b & 1 \\
\{c,0\} & 0 & c \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

I don't follow, why,

$a\land c$ = $c$ and $a\lor c$ =$a$, shouldn't it be vice versa ?

$a\land b$ = $0$ ?

$a\lor b$ = $1$ ?

It would be nice if someone could help me out here.

Comment: It seems to me that $a\wedge c=a$ and $a\vee c=c$ as you suggested
and $c\wedge b=0$. Off course $\left\{ b,c\right\} =\left\{ c,b\right\} $
but the outcomes $c\wedge b$ and $b\wedge c$ are different. Quite some things
are wrong here. $a\wedge b=0$ and $a\vee b=1$ looks correct to me ( I am not an
expert in this).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, the table is wrong in several places. Here is a corrected table:

$$\begin{array}{|c || c | c|}
\hline
\text{Subset} & x \wedge y & x \vee y \\
\hline
\{a,b\} & 0 & 1 \\
\{a,c\} & a & c \\
\{a,1\} & a & 1 \\
\{a,0\} & 0 & a \\
\{b,c\} & 0 & 1 \\
\{b,1\} & b & 1 \\
\{b,0\} & 0 & b \\
\{c,1\} & c & 1 \\
\{c,0\} & 0 & c \\
\hline
\end{array}$$

Now why do we have $a \wedge b = 0$ and $a \vee b = 1$? In terms of the Hasse diagram, $0$ is the first element "downwards accessible" from both $a$ and $b$; likewise for $1$, but "upwards".